# How to validate if at least one of multiple input fields is entered?

Tags: validation, jsf

I have a form with 3 fields, and submit button. when button clicked, if none is entered in 3 fields, throw validation message. If any one of the 3 fields are entered process the data and show results back in same page using data table. I am able to throw validation message for one field, but not for 2 fields or more.Here is my code. As well, if I have a long value that I need to pass, and validate how can i do that, since long value can not be validated as `isEmpty()` or `isNull()`.

Here is my code, I want to use it with multiple fields and with fields that have long values get validated.

```
<h:inputText id="userName" value="#{user.userName}" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Please enter username" />

<h:inputText id="empId" value="#{user.empId}" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Please enter Employee Id" />

<h:inputText id="acctNm" value="#{user.acctNm}" required="true" 
    requiredMessage="Please enter Employee Id" />
```

Comment: What is your question? Why can't you just change `search()` method to check all fields? Use `Long` to check for nulls.

Comment: even though I changed it to null, in the frontend it shows me a value 0 inside the textbox for long value. hwo can i get rid of populating 0? yes I can change the search method to check all fields, but How do I get them? If i use void method of faces context, UIComponent, Object value that does not work.

Comment: Add `empId` and `acctNm` to your `user` bean. Make thme both `java.lang.Long`.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, please press `Ctrl+Shift+F` before copypasting code. The one in the question is badly formatted which makes it harder to interpret.

Answer (score 6):

Just let the `required` attribute of each field check the presence of the submitted value of the other fields. The submitted value is available in the parameter map `#{param}` by the client ID as key.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText id="field1" ... required="#{empty param['form:field2'] and empty param['form:field3']}" />
    <h:inputText id="field2" ... required="#{empty param['form:field1'] and empty param['form:field3']}" />
    <h:inputText id="field3" ... required="#{empty param['form:field1'] and empty param['form:field2']}" />
</h:form>
```

It gets only more ugly as the amount of fields grows.

Alternatively, you can use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:validateOneOrMore>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrMore):

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText id="field1" ... />
    <h:inputText id="field2" ... />
    <h:inputText id="field3" ... />

    <o:validateOneOrMore id="oneOrMore" components="field1 field2 field3" />
    <h:message for="oneOrMore" />
</h:form>
```

Please note that performing validation in action method is bad design. You should use the standard JSF validation facilities for this such as `requiered`, `validator`, `<f:validator>` and/or `<f:validateXxx>`.

Comment: I am supposed to use icefaces1.8 actually,but since icefaces is not installed on my machine, I did it with jsf tags. Anyways..let us say if the validation passes, means user entered some value in one of the 3 fields, then I need to get the data to datatable on same page. can i use action or actionListener? HOW can i process those? inside validate method?

Comment: Just the usual way in the action method tied to the command button. The action method won't be invoked anyway when validation has failed. As to ICEfaces restriction; please note that OmniFaces is not a component library, it's an utility library. You can use it together with every JSF component library.

Comment: Thanks it works fine, only thing is can I get one error message instead of 3? like please enter atleast one value in one of the fields. Now I am getting error messages like this:form:userName: Validation Error: Value is required.form:empId: Validation Error: Value is required., form:acctNm: Validation Error: Value is required

Comment: Remove `required` from the other 2 fields or use `<o:validateOneOrMore>`.

Answer (score 0):

At least for iceFaces another approach to validate across multiple fields, especially when the validation is more complex than just "required", is to use application level validation inside your backing bean.

@see [Custom Validator in Backing Beans](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Validators#Validators-application)

- Add the validator attribute to you rcomponent and point it to teh validation method in your backing bean
- inside teh backing bean you can now access all form fields and do cross validation

Regards

Rob

Comment: That's not ICEfaces specific. That's just standard JSF. I suggest to invest some more time in learning basic JSF. After all, you're still not answering the concrete question in detail. You're merely giving a hint that it could be done with a custom JSF validator, but you're nowhere telling *how* exactly.