# Making AT-LEAST any one of Input Fields as Required in JSF Form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to make At-least any one of the filed as Required in a form.

For Example:

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
    <h:outputLabel value="User Name:"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{searchBean.userName}" id="user_name"/>

    <h:outputLabel value="Location:"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{searchBean.location}" id="location"/>

    <h:outputLabel value="Date of Birth"/>
    <p:calendar value="#{searchBean.dob}" id="dob"/>

    <p:commandButton value="Search"/>
</h:form>
```

In the above form has there are 3 Input Fields:

- user_name
- location
- dob

and it searches based on the given criteria.
I want to make User to enter **at-least any one** of the above Fields to be REQUIRED to make the search happen.
So how do i use **required** validation so that the above scenario will work.
Please suggest any wok around!

Comment: This is actually a better question: [How to validate if at least one of the 3 fields is entered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012197/how-to-validate-if-at-least-one-of-the-3-fields-is-entered/13013226#13013226), however the stupid new close system didn't let me pass that as possible duplicate as it didn't have any upvoted/accepted answer.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks I couldn't find those questions.

Comment: @BalusC:How about I put ajax on each input Field and check them in ActionListener and throw AbortProcessingException if all of them are null.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job. Use a validator to validate,  not an action listener.