# At least one/group of multiple fields required in JSF

Tags: validation, jsf

I'm trying to do a search function of which I have multiple fields and need at least one of them required, or a group of them.

The only answer I found on StackOverflow is this one: [How to validate if at least one of multiple input fields is entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012197/how-to-validate-if-at-least-one-of-multiple-input-fields-is-entered)

And there are 2 solutions there: One uses Omnifaces (which I can't use due to project requirements), and the other is not elegant, because it grows a lot when the number of fields is big.

I have these fields for example:

```
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{backingBean.type}"id="type">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{constantsController.SELECT_TYPE_HEADER}"
                        itemDisabled="true" />
                    <f:selectItems
                        value="#{constantsController.getTypes().entrySet()}"
                        var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:inputText id="number" value="#{backingBean.number}"/>

                <p:inputText id="year" value="#{backingBean.year}"/>

                <p:inputText id="number2" value="#{backingBean.number2 }"/>

                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{backingBean.state}"
                    id="state" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose its state" disabled="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{constantsController.getStates().entrySet()}"
                        var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:selectOneMenu id="entity"
                    value="#{backingBean.entity }">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select entity"
                        itemDisabled="true" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Entity1" itemValue="1"></f:selectItem>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Entity2" itemValue="2"></f:selectItem>
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:selectOneMenu id="documentType"
                    value="#{backingBean.documentType}">
                    <f:selectItems
                        value="#{constantsController.getDocumentTypes().entrySet()}"
                        var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:inputText id="documentNumber" value="#{backingBean.documentNumber}"/>
```

So as you can see, I have multiple fields. And the requirements dictate that I need one of the following required (I'll write the id's):

1- type + number + year

2- number2 + state

3- entity

4- documentType + documentNumber

So I when I click the commandButton, I need this to check if one of these groups (1, 2, 3 or 4) is filled.

Also, the groups in itself need to be required, i.e. let's say I already filled 'entity', and I also filled the 'year', it cannot let me advance since year needs to be accompanied by 'type' and 'number'.

Comment: You can do checking for required field/group in Java (server side), not on client side

Comment: Yes, that was my solution at the end of it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by associating a boolean in the backing bean to each of the fields/group of fields. It's not an elegant solution, but I wasn't finding any other solution.

So what I did was define by group of fields in the backing bean a boolean initialized with `true` value:

```
private boolean typeNumberYear = true;
private boolean number2State = true;
private boolean entityRequired = true;
private boolean documentTypeDocumentName = true;
private boolean masterRequired = true;
```

then to validate them:

```
public void checkRequiredFields(){

    if(!type.equals("") && number != 0 && year != 0)
        typeNumberYear = false;
    if(number2 != 0 && !state.equals(""))
        number2State = false;
    if(!entity.equals(""))
        entityRequired= false;
    if(!documentType.equals("") && documentNumber != 0)
        documentTypeDocumentName = false;

    if(!typeNumberYear || !number2State || !entityRequired || !documentTypeName)
        masterRequired = false;
}
```

Since all this is in the backing bean, I can just put this function on the actionListener of the command button, while the action function is still in the controller.

```
<p:commandButton value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search"
                actionListener="#{backingBean.checkRequiredFields}"
                action="#{controller.searchButtonClicked}"/>
```

Now in the `required` parameter I just associated the respective boolean and the masterRequired on all of them. E.g. in the `type`, `number` and `year` inputs, I put the required as follows:

`required = "backingBean.typeNumberYear and backingBean.masterRequired"`

The only downside to this solution, is that in the interface, there will be appearing an asterisk on all the fields that are indicated above, but if you just input the entity for example, it will search as it is supposed to, and then it will update and remove the asterisks.